# Different domain names assigned to the same IP address with different ports

Tags: dns, webserver, ip, port

Is there generally any issue with assigning different domain names to the same IP address on a server, but differentiating them by port number?

Is there anything unsafe, or considered bad practice with doing this?

Comment: What do you plan to do with them? Presumably not web serving...

Comment: It's pretty common to have several domains resolving to the same IP. You don't really need to use different ports.

Comment: @amenadiel I'm talking about the two domain names serving two different web sites.

Comment: I know. Your webserver should allow you to specify N vhosts, each ones listens for a particular host and has its own document root, so it serves different websites. There are exceptions (for example with node.js) that need additional configuration or proxy modules.

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly fine to associate multiple domains with a single IP address, and it's perfectly fine to only respond to queries on certain ports that meet whatever criteria you want to impose.

Whether it's *feasible* will vary on the protocol being used. For instance, if you were doing this with web serving, where (say) `http://example1.com:80` (80 being the default HTTP port) was supposed to do serve one thing and `http://example2.com:81` was supposed to serve something else, you'd be relying on the client issuing the request sending you the HTTP `Host:` header (nearly all will, it's a *really* important header and it's **required** in HTTP 1.1), so you could deny the example2.com requests on port 80 and the example1.com requests on port 81. (**Why** you would want to do that is a question; you could just use the standard port and vary the content you send back based on the `Host` header, that's extremely standard practice.)

But not all protocols tell you what domain the client looked up in order to find your IP address, so it may not be feasible to do this with other protocols.

---

Re your comment on the question and below on this answer:

> I'm talking about the two domain names serving two different web sites.
>
> The reason I want to do it is because we have exhausted the IP addresses that our hosting service has supplied on our web server and we have to pay to get more.

You don't need, and don't want, to use different ports for this. You can do it based on the `Host` header (see above). It's extremely standard practice. How you do it depends on your web server software. Apache calls this [name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html), but I'm sure it's possible with all major web server software.

Comment: The reason I want to do it is because we have exhausted the IP addresses that our hosting service has supplied on our web server and we have to pay to get more. Yes, I want to try to host two different web sites on the same IP address with two different domain names. I'm primarily a coder, server administration isn't exactly my forte'.

Comment: @Hypersapien: If you're talking about serving web content, you don't need (or want) to do this by port at all. I've added a note above. Specifics for how you do it with your web server software would be a question for either http://serverfault.com or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com (probably the former).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll ask there. For the record, this is Windows 2008 server with IIS 7.

Comment: @Hypersapien: This is quite easy in IIS7, you should be able to find the info in MSDN [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc772350(v=ws.10).aspx) should get you started.